# New file not found by Node.js server, only after server restart

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

While my Node.js server is running, a new (json) file is created in the public/data folder by another application. When I try to load the new file using jQuery's $.getJson function, it returns the 404 error:

```
 GET http://localhost:3003/data/dummy.json 404 (Not Found)
```

However, when I restart the server and try loading the same file again, it can be found without any problems. Is there a way to load the file without needing to restart the Nodejs server?

Update:
This is the function that loads the json-file:

```
public loadResource(url: any, callback: Function) {
    if (url && typeof url === 'string') {
        var success = false;
        $.getJSON(url, (resource: Resource) = > {
            success = true;
            resource.url = url;
            this.initResources(resource);
            callback();
        });
        setTimeout(() = > {
            if (!success) {
                console.log('Error while loading resources: ' + url);
                callback();
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, copy and paste the code of your server to see the problem.

Comment: Do you mean "restart the server without code modification" and it works fine?

Comment: @TaoP.R. Yes, the only difference is that I restart server.js, nothing in the code changes. Before restarting the file gives an 404 error, after restarting it loads correctly

Comment: Sounds like your server side code is caching the non-existence of the file you are looking for. You'd need to look at that, not your client side code, to figure out why.